# one of my drives not showing in list of thisPC

Tags: windows, disk, drive

[image: drive missing from list]

I had 7 drives, but after formatting the windows one of that drive(I:) not showing, help me to retrive that drive without loosing any data

Answer (score 0):

I think your drive is unmounted

https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/add-a-hard-drive-to-this-pc-in-windows-10.html

Answer (score 0):

your drive might missing the Drive Letter or path please follow the bellow method to assign a new letter

> click on windows 
>   search drive management ( click on "**Create or format hard disk partition**")

[image: hard disk management]

> right click on your missing drive and select "**Change Drive letter and path**"

[image: Change Drive letter and path]

> click on "**Add**"
>   select any one of the given letter

[image: assign letter]

> click **ok**
>   check the drive in **this pc**

[image: drive retrived]

> *tada*, drive retrived with all data

OR

If your drive is unmounted follow those steps: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/58667/mount-drive-windows/